# Connecting eclipse to my server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm not sure if this is possible, but we are doing a dynamic web project in school, (java,html,css,mysql) and we have a home server running (apache, tomcat, php, mysql) is there a way to connect Eclipse to that server so that i dont always have to pack a new war file and upload it through tomcat manager ? It would be easier if the result could be seen instantly on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse supports local tomcat deployment. To deploy to a remote tomcat you can either use [Maven](http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/introduction.html) or [Ant](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing%20Manager%20Commands%20With%20Ant).

There is a [cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/) plugin as well but personally I have not used. My preference is maven plugin.